# How to reduce writing between InputStreams and OutputStreams?

Tags: java, stream

I have the following use case:

- read from service `InputStream`
- go through the `InputStream` and replace some stuff, result is stored in `OutputStream`
- now I need to go on working with an `InputStream` created from the `OutputStream`

This is the code I use right now:

```
InputStream resourceStream = service.getStream();
ByteArrayOutputStream output = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
replace(resourceStream, output, ...);
resourceStream.close();
resourceStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(out.toByteArray());
```

A lot of shifting and converting streams, so I was wondering if there is a cleaner solution. Maybe some `OutputStream` which can be used as `InputStream`, or an `OutputStream` which contains an `InputStream` where the content is written to.

Comment: A stream is a stream. That means it's a serial-access, no-turning-back sequence of bytes. A better way would be to take one item from the original stream, pass it through all the stages of processing, and only then write it to a final output stream as needed.

Comment: So, this OutputStream should take data from InputStream as soon as thay appear there?

Comment: @PavloPlynko more like: data should be in the "new" `InputStream` as soon as it gets written into the `OutputStream`.

Answer (score 1):

No matter how good your idea of having a single object to write and read data from, the implementations of `InputStream` and `OutputStream` have been made as "Classes" and not "Interfaces".

Also, due to the fact that, in Java, a single subclass cannot extend multiple Super Classes, the dream of having both Input and Output stream operations in a single class remains just a dream.

That said, the only other option left for programmers would be to create a class that has both InputStream and OutputStream exposed to its clients. Something similar to what as `java.net.Socket` does. It exposes a `getInputStream` and a `getOutputStream` which at a logical level reads from and writes to the same "socket".

So, you can do something like this:

```
public class IOStreamWrapper {

    byte[] streamData;

    public InputStream getInputStream() {
        // return an inputstream that reads from streamData[]
    }

    public OutputStream getOutputStream() {
        // return an outputstream that writes to streamData[]
    }

}
```

References:

[Java InputStream](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html)

[Java OutputStream](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/OutputStream.html)

---

Hope this helps!